# Laravel Relations - Many to one

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

On the index page, I want to show the last 10 events. Every event has 4 participants (called users).

Event table example:

```
id, name, user_one, user_two, user_three, user_four, event_start_time, more_event_data...
```

In the controller I'm sending event data to the view:

```php
public function index()
{
    if( !AuthUserHasPermissionToRoute( 'event.index' ) )
        abort( 404 );
                
    return view( 'event.index' )
        ->with('event', Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get() );
}
```

Using the model I would like to send the user data as well

In the EventModel, I have tried hasMany (but will only with 1)

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany( User::class, 'id', 'user_one', 'id' );
}
```

And a Many-To-Many:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( User::class );
}
```

In the view, I'm trying to get the users name ( later possibly more ) to be displayed

```
{{ $game->users->user_one->name }}
{{ $game->users->user_two->name }}
{{ $game->users->user_three->name }}
{{ $game->users->user_four->name }}
```

But I can not get it to work, Could somebody show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If your event table have `user_one, user_two, user_three, user_four` user ids, then for the event table the relation should be `belongsTo`

**Event** Model

```
public function user_one()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class,'user_one', 'id');
}
public function user_two()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class,'user_two', 'id');
}
public function user_three()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class,'user_three', 'id');
}
public function user_four()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class,'user_four', 'id');
}
```

I would recommend make a different table as `user_events` and make `belongsToMany` relationship with it

Comment: Worked thanks! But I think you are right. Will rebuild to use an extra table

Comment: Glad to help you :) Happy coding.